# How to create a datetime object from a string?

Tags: python, datetime, split

I tried to be smart and create a one liner which can extract the datetime of `my_string` and make a datetime of it. However, it did not work quiet well.

```
my_string = 'London_XX65TR_20211116_112413.txt'
```

**This is my code:**

```
datetime=  datetime.datetime.strptime(my_string .split('_')[2],'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
```

**This is my output:**

```
ValueError: time data '20211116' does not match format '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S'
```

Comment: Strongly discouraged to use `datetime` as a variable name here since it is the name of a module which you are importing. Better to do something like `timestamp = datetime.datetime.strptime(...)`.

Answer (score 3):

You could use the `maxsplit` argument in [`str.split`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.split):

```
>>> from datetime import datetime
>>> region, code, date_time = my_string[:-4].split('_', maxsplit=2)
>>> datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 16, 11, 24, 13)
```

Which means only split at, at most `maxsplit` occurrences of the `_` characters from the left, leave the rest as is.

---

For this particular case, instead of `my_string[:-4]`, you could use `my_string.rstrip('.txt')`, it is not advised in general, because it may strip some useful information as well. Whereas, from `Python 3.9+` you could use [`str.removesuffix`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix):

```
>>> my_string = 'London_XX65TR_20211116_112413.txt'
>>> region, code, date_time = my_string.removesuffix('.txt').split('_', maxsplit=2)
>>> datetime.strptime(date_time, "%Y%m%d_%H%M%S")
datetime.datetime(2021, 11, 16, 11, 24, 13)
```

Comment: Nice tip with using str.removesuffix, however this should already be possible from python 3.9 on: https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html#str.removesuffix

Comment: @LeBavarois Thanks, started testing 3.10 so early I completely forgot this was added in 3.9. I'll update.

Answer (score 1):

You could use `re.findall` here:

```
from datetime import datetime

my_string = 'London_XX65TR_20211116_112413.txt'
ts = re.findall(r'_(\d{8}_\d{6})\.', my_string)[0]
dt = datetime.strptime(ts, '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
print(dt)  # 2021-11-16 11:24:13
```

This approach uses a regex to extract the timestamp from the input string.  The rest of your logic was already correct.

Answer (score 0):

The Method you are following is correct. It's just you are not considering the HH:MIN:Sec part and need to append that before formatting,

```
my_string = 'London_XX65TR_20211116_112413.txt'
my_date = (my_string .split('_')[2]+my_string .split('_')[3]).replace(".txt","")
datetime=  datetime.datetime.strptime(my_date,'%Y%m%d%H%M%S')
print(datetime) # 2021-11-16 11:24:13
```

Answer (score 0):

Your code does not work because `my_string .split('_')` gives `['London', 'XX65TR', '20211116', '112413.txt']` so in `strptime('20211116', '%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')` return an error.

You should either :

1. limit the format to `'%Y%m%d', loosing the HMS
2. find another way to get the whole substring matching the format

The first part of the alternative is trivial so lets go for the second one using regex.

```
import regex as re
datetime = datetime.datetime.strptime(re.search(r'\d{8}_\d{6}', my_string)[0],'%Y%m%d_%H%M%S')
```

Answer (score 0):

```py
from datetime import datetime

date_time_str = '18/09/19 01:55:19'

date_time_obj = datetime.strptime(date_time_str, '%d/%m/%y %H:%M:%S')


print ("The type of the date is now",  type(date_time_obj))
print ("The date is", date_time_obj)
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).